# How to enable vs2017 go to definition for third party C++ library

Tags: c++, visual-studio

vs2017 only brings me to the header file. Now I have to manually search for the definition in the third party library src directory using notepad++. I searched on the web for the solution but with no luck. Is is possible?

Comment: Do you have the source of the 3rd party library?

Comment: @user0042 Of course. That why I can search for the definition using notepad++.

Comment: You can add the header and source as search paths to your project folder, and just search for symbols there.

Comment: if you open the source file of the library, will VS go to the definition ?

Comment: @xyious Yes. I just tried.

Comment: @user0042 I suppose it's `Source Directories`. I don't know why its not working as Microsoft specifies it's the `Directories in which to search for source files to use for IntelliSense.`